# Groovy : Compare a float value in the list and find out values which are greater than the float value

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I want to compare one float value to a list and find out the values which are greater than the float value in the list and print them. Note that the float value will also be available in the list.

for example:

```
float_value = 11.6
list = [9.1,9.2,9.7,10.1,10.5,11.1,11.5,11.6,11.9,12.0,12.5,12.9,13.0]
```

So I want to compare `11.6` with the list and find out the values which are greater than 11.6. Output could be something like.

```
final_list = [11.9,12.0,12.5,12.9,13.0]
```

Could someone help me out to achieve this in groovy code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Collection[`.findAll`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll()) method:

```
final_list = list.findAll { it > float_value }
```